# Meaning of asterisk slash asterisk sequence in Rails' log?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, curl, browser, character

I'm using `curl` to test the output of my page for SEO purposes. The log output is different from if I'd use a browser, even `lynx`. The difference starts from this line:

```
Processing by Controller#action as */*
```

While when using a browser, I'm getting this:

```
Processing by Controller#action as HTML
```

So what is the meaning of `*/*`?

Comment: The meaning of */* means the type of request(js / html etc), you need to pass the request type in curl as well

Comment: You're right. I'm wondering just what exactly the meaning of the whole - asterisk and slash and asterisk? If you feel like you can answer below.

Comment: sorry actually in my above comment there is typing mistake. The meaning of `*/*  means the type of request(js / html etc), `*/* means the blank request request type, you need to pass the request type in curl as well, and when you hit the same page from browser the browser will append the request type as html